# How do I fix / isntall the drivers for my touchpad for Lenovo Yoga 900 i5

Tags: drivers, touchpad, lenovo

I've just installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my new Lenovo Yoga 900 (Skylake Core i5-6200U CPU).

The touch-pad doesn't appear to be working at all so I have to use an extra port for Mouse (not to mention the fact that the touchscreen is not working either but that's not important).

I understand that the **ideapad_laptop** drivers are not working perfectly in Ubuntu for this machine and this is why I have added:

```
modprobe -r ideapad_laptop
```

in **my /etc/rc.local** file and

```
blacklist ideapad_laptop
```

in my  **/etc/modprobe.d**  file

but without success...

Any idea what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello i have had the same problem. This https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=204355 helped me to solve. it works good except after supend. So this steel  to be solved.

Comment: Which part of the forum thread had helped you? Should quote relevant text in your answer.

Comment: it looks like kernel version 4.4.0 is the solution...

Comment: the guide for building the software package is here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2307518&p=13418712#post13418712

Comment: after supend, if touch pad does not work, just use [ctrl-f1] [ctrl-f7] to fixe the problem. all seems to work properly now.